# Mysqli query inside query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have few separate tables in mysql which are named `tblstudent` and `tblskill`. The `tblskill` holds data based on `studentId`. The problem now is when I want to display the data, the displayed data will be duplicated depending on how many skill that ID holds. Any idea how to fix this? This is screenshot how my data is displayed [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1spi.jpg) this is my `tblskill`

```
attributes[skillId(int),skill(varchar),studentId(varchar)]
```

This is my code:

```
<?php 

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tblstudent.id,tblstudent.studentId,tblstudent.programme,tblstudent.cgpa,tblpersonalinfo.studentId,tblpersonalinfo.pImage,tblpersonalinfo.pImageType,tblpersonalinfo.pImageSize,tblpersonalinfo.pName FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN tblpersonalinfo ON tblstudent.studentId = tblpersonalinfo.studentId ".$where_sql."  ");

  if ($result->num_rows != 0) {



  echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='0' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
  echo "<tbody>";



 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  $studentId = $row[1];


 // get data from db


  echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row[0]."'>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>";
  echo '<div  class="title bg-primary" align="left" style="font-weight: bold;">' .   '&nbsp;' .  '<img src="uploads/' . $row['pImage'] .' " alt = "avatar" height="60" width="50" >' . '&nbsp;' . $row['pName'] . '&nbsp;' . '&nbsp;' . '&nbsp;' . '<a href="viewResume.php?id=' .  $row[0]  . ' " target="_blank" >'.'<img src="image/viewResume.png" alt="Apply Now" width="100" height="40" border="0">'.'</a>'. '</div>';
  echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['programme']. '</div>';





  include('Connections/connect.php');


    if ($result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tblskill WHERE studentId=$studentId"))
    {
  if ($result1->num_rows != 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {

      echo "<table class='scroll' width='700' border='0' bgcolor='#FF00FF' align='left'>";
     echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>";
     echo '<div  align="left" class="sub">' . '<br>' . $row['skill']. '</div>';
     echo "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</tbody>";
     echo "</table>";

}
}
}

  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . '&nbsp;' . '</td>';
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT tblstudent.id,tblstudent.studentId,tblstudent.programme,tblstudent.cgpa,tblpersonalinfo.studentId,tblpersonalinfo.pImage,tblpersonalinfo.pImageType,tblpersonalinfo.pImageSize,tblpersonalinfo.pName FROM tblstudent INNER JOIN tblpersonalinfo ON tblstudent.studentId = tblpersonalinfo.studentId ".$where_sql."  ");
```

Add to your queries DISTINCT after SELECT
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: theres nothing change in the output..what should i do to the second query?

Comment: Have you tried to do the same with the second query?